# Should I manually write out "sub-results" in C++?

Tags: c++

In a piece of my code I compute a `mat4` from 3 `const vec3`s:

```
const vec3 position{...}, orientation{...}, scale{...};

float mat[4][4]
{
    {
        (2 * scale.x * cos(orientation.y + orientation.z) + scale.x * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) - scale.x * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) + 2 * scale.x * cos(orientation.y - orientation.z) - scale.x * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) + scale.x * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z)) / 4,
        (-scale.x * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y) + scale.x * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y)) / 2,
        (-2 * scale.x * sin(orientation.y + orientation.z) - scale.x * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) + scale.x * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) + 2 * scale.x * sin(orientation.y - orientation.z) - scale.x * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) + scale.x * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z)) / 4,
        0
    },
    {
        (-scale.y * cos(orientation.x + orientation.z) + scale.y * cos(orientation.x - orientation.z)) / 2,
        scale.y * cos(orientation.x),
        (scale.y * sin(orientation.x + orientation.z) + scale.y * sin(orientation.x - orientation.z)) / 2,
        0
    },
    {
        (2 * scale.z * sin(orientation.y + orientation.z) + scale.z * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) + scale.z * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) + 2 * scale.z * sin(orientation.y - orientation.z) - scale.z * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) - scale.z * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z)) / 4,
        (-scale.z * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y) - scale.z * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y)) / 2,
        (2 * scale.z * cos(orientation.y + orientation.z) + scale.z * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) + scale.z * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) - 2 * scale.z * cos(orientation.y - orientation.z) + scale.z * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) + scale.z * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z)) / 4,
        0
    },
    {
        (-2 * position.y * cos(orientation.x + orientation.z) + 2 * position.x * cos(orientation.y + orientation.z) + position.x * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) - position.x * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) + 2 * position.y * cos(orientation.x - orientation.z) + 2 * position.x * cos(orientation.y - orientation.z) - position.x * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) + position.x * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z) + 2 * position.z * sin(orientation.y + orientation.z) + position.z * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) + position.z * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) + 2 * position.z * sin(orientation.y - orientation.z) - position.z * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) - position.z * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z)) / 4,
        (2 * position.y * cos(orientation.x) - position.x * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y) + position.x * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y) - position.z * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y) - position.z * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y)) / 2,
        (2 * position.z * cos(orientation.y + orientation.z) + position.z * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) + position.z * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) - 2 * position.z * cos(orientation.y - orientation.z) + position.z * cos(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) + position.z * cos(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z) + 2 * position.y * sin(orientation.x + orientation.z) - 2 * position.x * sin(orientation.y + orientation.z) - position.x * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y + orientation.z) + position.x * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y + orientation.z) + 2 * position.y * sin(orientation.x - orientation.z) + 2 * position.x * sin(orientation.y - orientation.z) - position.x * sin(orientation.x + orientation.y - orientation.z) + position.x * sin(orientation.x - orientation.y - orientation.z)) / 4,
        1
    }
};
```

As you can see, the computation consists of only a few simple operations (`+`, `-`,`*`,`/`, `sin` and `cos`), but many of them appear many times. Examples of such operations are:

```
orientation.y + orientation.z
orientation.x + oy_plus_oz
sin(orientation.x - oy_plus_oz)
//many more...
```

I don't want the processor to calculate them multiple times, so instead I tried to replace them with "shortucts":

```
float oy_plus_oz = orientation.y + orientation.z;
float cos_oy_plus_oz = cos(oy_plus_oz);
float ox_plus_oy_plus_oz = orientation.x + oy_plus_oz;
float ox_minus_oy_plus_oz = orientation.x - oy_plus_oz;
float oy_minus_oz = orientation.y - orientation.z;
float ox_plus_oy_minus_oz = orientation.x + oy_minus_oz;
float ox_minus_oy_minus_oz = orientation.x - oy_minus_oz;
float cos_ox_plus_oy_plus_oz = cos(ox_plus_oy_plus_oz);
float cos_ox_minus_oy_plus_oz = cos(ox_minus_oy_plus_oz);
float two_mult_sx = 2 * scale.x;
float cos_oy_minus_oz = cos(oy_minus_oz);
float cos_ox_plus_oy_minus_oz = cos(ox_plus_oy_minus_oz);
float cos_ox_minus_oy_minus_oz = cos(ox_minus_oy_minus_oz);
float ox_plus_oy = orientation.x + orientation.y;
float ox_minus_oy = orientation.x - orientation.y;
float cos_ox_plus_oy = cos(ox_plus_oy);
float cos_ox_minus_oy = cos(ox_minus_oy);
```

**Is there a better/faster way to do it, or is it unnecessary altogether?** The key is that this code should be as fast as possible (avoid unnecessary computation of the same value multiple times).

Comment: Always when trying to optimize, dont try and predict what the compiler will do. Even if someone told you that the first option was faster it might not be true on a different compiler. Instead try both methods on your compiler and time them.

Comment: If the topmost values are compile time constants, then you can use constexpr. That will help

Comment: [Common Subexpression (CSE) elimination](http://compileroptimizations.com/category/cse_elimination.htm) is subject to implementation quality of compiler (in addition trigo functions should be tagged as pure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better/faster way to do it, or is it unnecessary altogether? The key is that this code should be as fast as possible (avoid unnecessary computation of the same value multiple times).

An optimizing compiler will look for equivalent expressions that are faster to compute, including factoring out subexpressions.

Which way will end up with the best code is impossible to say without taking a look into the generated code and measuring actual execution times (and what is the optimal solution may depend on the CPU you are targeting).

However, in general, computing repeated expressions first is usually clearer for humans, aids debugging and may simplify the optimizer's life too.

Also, since this is about floating-point calculations, and therefore order matters, it is very important to check carefully the build flags you are passing to the optimizer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do I have to write all these operations by hand or could it somehow be automized?

Comment: What do you mean? What are you trying to automate?

Comment: Writing out all those variables such as `sin_two_mult_ox_plus_oy_minus_oz`. Its very tedious.

Comment: You should try to write intermediate results that make logical sense in the domain, not just factoring out everything for the sake of it (the optimizer will do that). In other words, if you are simply going to write things like `sin_two_mult_ox_plus_oy_minus_oz`, don't do it.

Comment: checking attributes (as "pure") of trigo functions is also important.